# Each dictionary entry must have an associated key

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a class that inherits `IDictionary` named `ResourceDictionary`.
Also I have another class with the attribute `DictionaryKeyProperty` named `Style`.
The `DictionaryKeyProperty` is named `TargetType`.

XAML file content:

```
<ResourceDictionary
             xmlns="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Test"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <Style TargetType="test" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It is giving the error **`Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.`**

```
public class ResourceDictionary : IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, INameScope, ISupportInitialize
{
   ...
}

[ContentProperty("Setters"), DictionaryKeyProperty("TargetType")]
public class Style : Sealable, INameScope, IQueryAmbient, IResources
{

    private Type _TargetType;
    [Ambient]
    public Type TargetType
    {
        get { return _TargetType; }
        set
        {
            CheckSealed();
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            _TargetType = value;
        }
    }

    ......

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I solve this problem?

P.S.: I want to make a light framework that includes a Dependency System like WPF.

Answer (score 1):

The XAML compiler is complaining because your style definition is lacking the Key attribute.

Changing it to:

```
<Style x:Key="someKey" TargetType="test" />
```

.. will make the error go away but since I suspect that you wanted to declare a default style for your control the would require you to always reference that style using

```
<Test Style="{StaticResource someKey}" />
```

Which is probably not what you had in mind.

Could you update the question with the code for class "test"?

Comment: is this an answer..? or a new question? I can't decide.. May I suggest that you remove the question and explain how he could use `Dictionary` instead?

Comment: I want to create a small framework only use System.Xaml, and no WPF include.

Comment: More details please. I can't follow you.

Comment: 'DictionaryKeyProperty' used to set a 'Property' to 'x:Key' for 'IDictionary' collection. And my Xaml content build success and it can be load too. But it just show error in XAML designer.